# Gdb pretty printer is not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gdb

I have debugged C++ codes using `gdb` in Ubuntu 14.04. When I pass a `stl` container to the `print` command, it used to print the contents of the container. But then I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS a week back. Now those pretty printers are not working. When I print them I get those raw container output you get when you don't have python printers installed.

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738334/gdb-pretty-printing-is-not-working) also has the same problem.

I have `libstdcxx/v6/python.py`on my system. I also have `libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py` in the auto-load folder. When I print info pretty-printer in `gdb`, I get a list of `stl` printers, so I know they are registered.  However, my `gdb` doesn't print `stl::list` variable. i have enabled `pretty-printer`, set print pretty on.

My gcc version is 5.4 and gdb version is 7.11.1.Both were installed along with Ubuntu 16.04. I haven't built them manually. So anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `~/.gdbinit` file had a line:

> `sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gcc-4.8/python/')`

It turned out that changing it into:  (4.8->5)

> `sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gcc-5/python/')`

helped.